# framework for a databased crossplatform GUI application

Tags: database, user-interface, frameworks, gtk

I would like to develope a databased GUI application for free, which is cross-platform. I **almost** decided, that the UI should be GTK (logical, not pixel-based layout, GUI description not cluttering the code (glade xml))...

What I am missing is a good framework, which connects database and GUI, so I am looking for building database gui app.

Any suggestions? (ask me for more details if I am not concrete enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Dabo](http://dabodev.com/) for this. It is a GUI application framework for building apps around a database. It uses wxWindows for the GUI toolkit which is a bit higher level than just GTK. And you write your code in Python.

Comment: hm, maybe I looked at wxWindows (wxWidgets) long ago, but it looked to me a legacy framework

Comment: wxWidgets is still actively developed, last release in Sept 2009, and similarly wxPython was last released in May 2009. So the legacy bit is just a long history. These frameworks are still alive and active. Of course, if you chose wxPython, you could just pick up SQLAlchemy for the database bit, and not worry about the extra features of DABO. Even though wxPython + SQLAlchemy doesn't have any connection between DB and GUI, it is trivial to add that bit.

Comment: Well, I don't want to say it is not actively developed, but it smells a bit it suffers from too agressive backward-compatible piece. But will sure look into dabo. Ah, you mean "higher level", that wxWidgets can display itself with gtk, windows forms ...

Comment: But using macros (well, in the C++ tutorial), criptic constanst for identifying which button was pressed smells like legacy stuff :(

Answer (score 1):

The natural choice, if GTK+ is used, would be [libgda](http://www.gnome-db.org/): it provides a quite advanced abstraction layer on more database engines. There is another ongoing project, [gsql](http://gsql.org), but I don't know anything about it and I didn't understand the differences between them either.

Comment: Isn't it gnome only (which implies it is linux only)?

Comment: @pihentagy: libgda does not have any gnome dependency. In the download page it is packaged for windows too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Glom](http://www.glom.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page), seems to do a lot what you want.